# MySQl Stored Procedure passing Parameters with parameter name and values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a stored procedure.

```
create procedure uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem
(
    p_id int,
    p_name varchar(50),
    p_head int,
    p_desc varchar(500),
    p_ct_nm varchar(50)
)
begin
    declare p_returnvalue int;
    declare p_ct_cd int ;
    set p_ct_cd = (select ct_cd from com_typ where ct_nm = p_ct_nm);

    if (p_id is null) then
        insert into com_mst(
            ct_cd,
            cm_nm,
            cm_hed,
            cm_dsg
        )
        values
        (
            p_ct_cd,
            p_name,
            p_head,
            p_desc
        ) ;
        select p_returnvalue = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    else
        update com_mst set
            ct_cd=p_ct_cd,
            cm_nm=p_name,
            cm_hed =p_head,
            cm_dsg = p_dsg 
        where cm_cd = p_id ;
        select p_returnvalue = p_id;
    end if ;
end
```

and when I am executing this

```
call uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem (p_name := 'kk',p_head := '1',p_desc := 'des',p_ct_nm := 'Department')
```

it is showing error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 'k
>   k',p_head := '1',p_desc := 'des',p_ct_nm := 'Department')' at line 1

Comment: try passing only the parameters rather than assigning them while executing.

Comment: ID param is not past, you call starts from p_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the call method from

```
call uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem (p_name := 'kk',p_head := '1',p_desc := 'des',p_ct_nm := 'Department')
```

to

```
call uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem ('kk',1,'des','Department')
```

Also please pass the value for "p_id" as the first parameter on above call method

Comment: sir..  i know about your company bhubeneswar. thanks for answering but that is not what i wanted, i have 5 parameter in sp and want to pass only 4 parameter in call usp*.

Comment: i don't want to pass p_id , plz look at if else condition.. this sp is used for two operation, one for save and other for edit

Comment: For the operation you don't want to pass p_id, you have to pass a null value for that.

For the first parameter you have to pass "call uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem ('','kk',1,'des','Department')".

So that it will check the if and else condition and work on the code which is present in the under statement.

And for the value you want to pass for p_id. Pass a value in the place of NULL value

"call uspCommonMasterInsertUpdateSingleItem (123,'kk',1,'des','Department')".

Comment: sir.. do u have any opening in .net

Answer (score 0):

Give the parameter in the exact order as given in the proc. you have left out p_id in the execution.